# Amasty Color Swatch extension for Magento - options disappear when logged in as a wholesale customer

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Im using Amasty Color Swatch extension for Magento, and when logged in as a wholesale customer, the options disappear completely when one is selected on the product list view.

Im getting a javascript error in the console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElements' of null
```

in configurableList.js:374

This is the code at that location:

```
Product.Config.prototype.selectImage = function(image)
{
    var attributeId = image.parentNode.parentNode.id.replace(/[a-z-]*/, '');
    $('amconf-images-' + attributeId).childElements().each(function(child){
        child.childElements().each(function(children){
            children.removeClassName('amconf-image-selected');
        });
    });
    image.addClassName('amconf-image-selected');
}
```

Is there an error here? Works fine as a retailer but get this once logged in as wholesale.

Comment: Maybe you have conflict prototype and jquery libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably when customer is logged in the price block is rendered a bit differently for your custom theme, which leads to incorrect integration of our extension.

I believe it's possible to fix that by modifying selector in the extension code.

We'd be happy to help if you contact us and provide your access details both with the URL of page where this happens. You can do it here: https://amasty.com/contacts/